# Issue with fixed positioned element in modal in Firefox only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

Please take a look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WFa9/1/).

```
$('.approver-types').css("position", "fixed");
```

If you open in IE or Chrome, you can see what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm trying to have the roles element in the modal on the left fixed so that when you scroll the users checkbox list on the right, the roles don't move.  When you open the modal in Firefox, the roles list position is messed up until you click on something in the modal at which point it corrects itself.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Seems to be working correctly in Firefox 24.0, which version are you running?

Comment: You are applying fixed positon but you don't put `top` and `left`... Why ? That's what is tripping you. You are saying: "Be fixed, but I don't care where."

Comment: @JoshRutherford : Firefox 28.0.  This just became an issue all of the sudden so I'm wondering if the newest of FF broke it.
@drip: Setting `top` or `left` to anything won't work when the modal fades in nor will it work in my full implementation where you can move the modal around.

Comment: @drip: Absolute doesn't accomplish what I want; to lock the roles so it doesn't scroll with the users list.  Open the original jsfiddle in IE or Chrome to see what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block` instead of `display:table` in your nav-pills

In addition I added a piece of logic you were missing in your JS. You specified that it should apply the fixed position when the openFixed btn was clicked, but left the JS to guess what to do with the open btn. SO I added the missing logic

```
$('#open').on('click', function () {
    open();
    $('.approver-types').css("position", "static");
});
```

See the updated [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2WFa9/8/) and the [***VIDEO***](http://screencast.com/t/nZGvDcAAa) as well

Comment: @im1dermike Perhaps you have a bug somewhere else? My FF28 is rendering it beautifully.

Comment: I'm having the problem with your jsfiddle.  You're able to scroll down the users list and the roles stays fixed?

Comment: So your issue is that is not fixing? Becasue when I opened it, it was displaying outside of the modal and fllickering back and forth. However, now that is not flickering, you can adjust the fixed coordinated. I'll go back to the fiddle

Comment: Nice! I love the video software! lol. Had to download it. Anyway, I fixed the Open Modal, I didn't fix teh fixed modal. I'll get back to you in a minute

Comment: A picture (video) is worth a thousand words ;).  Yeah the "Open fixed modal" is what I'm shooting for.  The "Open modal" was just there to show that a non-fixed position worked.

Comment: No problem. I see you got your answer above. Did that satisfy your question or is there anything else?

Comment: The issue still remains.  It is still not displaying properly and locking the roles element in FF.

Comment: I updated my answer (several times over) lol I thought you rcss had issues and then I realized it was in fact your logic in the JS after all. Good luck!